# Simple song CRUD application with a music app

Tags: django-models, django-views, django-forms, crud

simple song CRUD application. In our models.py file inside the “musicapp” application we created, you are expected to add the following Models and Attributes.

Model: Artiste, Song, Lyric Attributes for “Artiste” : first_name, last_name, age Attributes for “Song”: title, date released, likes, artiste_id Attributes for “Lyric”: content, song_id

As you might have guessed, there is a relationship between all three Models. An Artiste can have multiple songs, and a song can have multiple lyrics. A song must only belong to one Artiste and a lyric must only belong to a song.

I am new to django and i am trying out this new task.

Comment: Did not get the question here? What do you expect us to answer?

Comment: @mika 
I did like to see your code with respect to:
 - How you specify the models in the models.py 

- How you specify the relationship between the models

 - How you specify the field-type for each attribute

 - How you Specify your Foreign Key